# Bootstrap site - google analytics pageviews not registering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-analytics, analytics

We migrated our old site to a new bootstrap site. I have the analytics added to the index.html which has the common elements to all our pages. I am checking the Google Analytics and it's not showing any pageviews or any visits for that matter.

Comment: Can you see hits in real-time?

Comment: You will need to show us your code and you will need to provide more details and information, please.